# How to correctly create a reusable boilerplate?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I've been using a lot of React Native, and always going thru `react-native init xxx` and setting up the same structure of `src` directories and `dependencies` such as `redux-thunk`, `redux` and so on, for each and every project.

So I'm thinking to instead of going thru the process everytime, I would like to create a boilerplate, that allow me to be very quickly to start a new React Native project.

So what I've done is go thru `react-native init boilerplate` and setup manually for `redux`, `react-navigation` and so on, and uploading this "boilerplate" onto github.

Now my question is, is this the right way to create a boilerplate? As I find a difficulty in renaming all "boilerplate" to "newProjectName". Wondering if any of you created boilerplate before and mind to share on how you guys tackle this problem?

Comment: Are you saying you want to change the name of the package easily?

Comment: @hongdevelop: Yes, also bundleID and all the created file related to filename

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the package name of the `iOS` bundle and `Android`, you can use the module. `react-native-rename`

**Usage**

```
react-native-rename <newName> -b <bundleIdentifier>
```

**Example**

```
react-native-rename "Travel App" -b com.junedomingo.travelapp
```

useful link:
[rename github](https://github.com/junedomingo/react-native-rename)

Comment: From your understanding do I still have anything else to watch out when I'm creating such boilerplate?

Comment: @Isaac It seems important to check where you are using it and back up your files because changing the name or file name can cause problems in the hidden path.